How to get ARA-M rules (e.g. list SHA-1 hashes of allowed apps) of an eUICC?
I have found online that the AID of ARA-M is A00000015141434C00, however trying to select it fails on my Thales eUICC card. Is the ARA-M AID for eUICC different from that of usual UICC?
Here are APDU commands I run:
0070000000 <- open logical channel, in this case 1 (status 019000)
01A4040009A00000015141434C00 <- select ARA-M AID

APDU Return status of the last command is 6A82 (file not found)
I've also tried 81CAFF4000 (command that should read certificate list I believe) but it failed as I would predict since select AID failed.
